# must PS1 string be reevaluated each time input enter

Tags: bash, variable, prompt

How to make the PS1 string always be reevaluated each time the user inputs the enter key at the shell prompt?

actual in mine:

```
n=A; PS1="$n"


n=B
```

The prompt keeps showing A. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $PS1 variable is using $n once because $n is evaluated and replaced with its value when $PS1 is initially set.  This is because you are using double quotes, in bash, it evaluates the variables in the double-quoted string in an assignment.

If you want your $PS1 to reflect the current value of $n, you need to either have single quotes around the $n or escape the dollar sign.

For example:

```
PS1='$n'
```

Or

```
PS1="\$n"
```